# Can I load a file once and access it repeatedly without reloading it?

Tags: php

I've inherited several PHP scripts that parse data from CSV files and update a database.  The CSV files are hundreds of MB, and a significant portion of time spent running the scripts is loading the CSVs.

I would like to maintain the CSVs in memory in-between running the scripts.  Is it possible to do this with PHP?

Comment: ... How many times do you need to process them to bring them into the database?

Comment: import to Database and manipulate there, it looks so pointless to do that ..

Comment: Maybe if you read the file as a stream, and process it as it comes in, it will work better? You can also use the SPLFileObject for parsing .csv's

Comment: If the files are for updating a database, don't they change between calls? So maintaining a previous copy in memory wouldn't help. Aside from that a) PHP on it's own cannot do this. The closest it has is sessions, but these are still maintained on disk, not in memory. You would have to sub the job out to something like memcached b) storing hundreds of MBs of redundant data in memory sounds like a *bad plan*...

Comment: I inherited this code, and I'm bug-fixing it.  The data won't be changing while I fix the issues.  I'm just trying to speed up development; waiting 20 seconds to load the CSVs every iteration is frustrating.

Comment: @Toast Can you elaborate on what you are actually doing with the data and can we see the code you are using? With that much data I would say what you want to be doing is stepping through the file and handling it row-by-row, rather than loading the whole thing into memory and then dealing with it. PHP arrays (which I would imagine is what you are using to store the data have a load of bloat which will add ~100 bytes *to each row* you store in memory - so if you have 10000 rows that's a whole extra MB of memory usage.

Comment: An old ecommerce website was rebuilt and I'm importing data from the old DB (CSV).  The programmer who wrote the import scripts quit, and it was discovered that they don't work 100%.  His scripts load the CSVs, processes the data, and load it into the new DB.  I'm trying to debug my way through it, but it takes several hours to run the whole scripts.  I've cut the data processed to a tiny fraction, but just loading the CSVs still takes 20+ seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done smoothly with a database support, preferably MySQL. You may import data from CSV into a temporary database and destruct that after the whole processing is done.

You can read about importing CSV data into database **[*here*](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/246795/how-to-import-.csv-into-mysql-database-in-php-)**

Comment: I imagine that would speed it up.  I'm thinking about throwing the files into memcached too, but then I have to install memcached.  Thanks!